# How to make a plist file from a Word file

Tags: ms-word, plist, quotes

I`m new to iPhone programming, and I'm trying to find my way around some books and sites for learning.

I have a word file with about 200 quotes from the author, and I want to make an "iPhone quote" APP. How can I create a plist from it?

Note that each quote has two fields: the quote itself and the source (book) from which the quote was selected. I want to add them to a table view in my App in a way that the beginning of the quote be the text, and the book source be the subtitle in the cell style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. All I had to do is create a template plist files in my xcode project, with a few rows, then I click to view as source (the XML tree). Then I can copy the tags before and after each quote, and paste them in my word file.
Once this is ready I copied the contents of the word file to Text Edit, removed all format, and copied that to the plis as source. It worked fine!